# Second stage of Pollard's p-1 algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, primes, factorization

I am implementing Pollard's p-1 algorithm in Python as described in Pollard's paper *Theorems on factorization and primality testing* . So far I have implemented the first stage of the algorithm which I did in the following way:

```
def factorizePminus1(n, B1, c):
    g = 1
    if(gcd(c,n) != 1):
        return gcd(c,n)
    primesUpToB1 = primes(B1)
    for p in primesUpToB1:
        pp = p
        while pp < B1:
            c = pow(c, p, n)
            pp = pp * p
    g = gcd(c-1, n)
    if(1<g<n):
        return g
    elif(g==n):
        return "Your factors are probably less than " + str(B1)
```

I implemented gcd by using Euclid's algorithm and generate a list of all the primes less than B1 by using primes(B1) which uses the sieve of Eratosthenes method. I am choosing my exponent to be `P = lcm(1,2,...,B1)`.

However, Pollard describes in his article a second stage of the algorithm in which one chooses a second bound B2 and computes the sequence of numbers `F_m = b^m-1 (mod n)` for `b=a^{lcm(1,2,...,B1)}` for primes `B1< m < B2` and hope to find an m such that `gcd(F_m,N)>1`.

The proposed way to do this in the article is to multiply b^m for all odd integers m between B1 and B2, which I did like this:

```
def factorizePminus1(n, B1, B2,c):
   g = 1
   if(gcd(c,n) != 1):
       return gcd(c,n)
   primesUpToB1 = primes(B1)
   for p in primesUpToB1:
       pp = p
       while pp < B1:
           c = pow(c, p, n)
           pp = pp * p
   g = gcd(c-1, n)
   if(1<g<n):
       return g
   elif(g==n):
       return "Your factors are probably less than " + str(B1)

   k = 0
   for q in range(primesUpToB1[-1],B2,2):
       c = pow(c,q,n)
   g = gcd(c-1,n)

   if(1<g<n):
       return g
   else:
       return "no luck"
```

There is another way proposed in the article which is to compute in advance a table of the residues b^2,b^4,b^(2D) up to the largest occurring difference of two consecutive primes p_{k+1}-p_k = 2D but this requires to generate a list of primes between B1 and B2 which would mean that I have to use primes(B2) which makes my program slow. I was wondering if there is a way to compute the primes between B1 and B2 given that I already have all primes less than B1 and how much more efficient is this to just simply computing all odd integers between B1 and B2?